# Hover over one element and select all elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, svg, onmouseover

Please see my HTML code. There is a green map and when hovering over it, it should change the color to yellow. The problem is, that there are separate SVG graphics (island), that not change their color.

Is there a JavaScript solution, that all SVG paths change their color, when mouse is over only one SVG path?

```css
.cls-4 {
  fill: #7ec353;
  stroke: #020202;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.cls-4:hover {
  fill: #d1b308;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">

  <svg id="Terrain" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4280.57 5494.61">
        
                <g id="0-250m">
                    
                    <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1237.03,239.22c4.1-5.74,1.62-16.81,0-26.24-1.64-9.41-2.05-6.54-8.6-8.6-6.57-2.05-11.08,.41-25.81,0-14.77-.41-32.79-4.52-34.86-4.9-2.03-.43-1.62,4.9-4.51,8.59-2.87,3.69-4.9,4.91-4.9,14.34s2.87,10.24,9.01,14.35c6.14,4.1,15.16,11.06,28.27,12.29,13.11,1.23,20.09,0,30.32,0s6.96-4.08,11.07-9.83Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1142.37,233.9c-4.08-4.11-5.74-4.91-9.83,0-4.08,4.92-11.88,21.71-12.28,26.64-.43,4.9-2.06,15.96,2.24,21.3,4.3,5.32,6.76,12.7,11.69,15.57,4.92,2.87,4.92,9.43,11.05,0,6.16-9.44,7.39-6.57,2.87-13.11-4.51-6.57-13.5-10.67-12.91-16.4,.63-5.73-1.43-16.81,1.86-21.3,3.26-4.49,9.41-8.59,5.31-12.7Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1239.27,361.34c1.45,6.54,1.4,11.49,5.11,15.16,3.73,3.69,16.83,12.27,20.93,7.79,4.11-4.51,10.24-15.57,9.85-20.48-.41-4.92,5.73-9.44,7.77-13.93,2.06-4.52,.84-9.03-5.31-8.61-6.16,.39-11.42,0-16.16,2.45-4.74,2.47-23.62,11.06-22.17,17.63Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1255.47,332.24c3.7-2.87,6.78-.8,6.04-4.3-.7-3.47-1.21-8.4-6.51-8.81-5.26-.39-4.38-1.42-5.26-.39-2.43,2.74,2.05,16.37,5.73,13.5Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1301.37,281.85c4.93-5.34,8.61-9.03,2.87-13.12-5.75-4.08-6.27,.43-7.62,0-1.39-.41-13.27,10.67-8.76,15.58,4.51,4.92,8.61,2.87,13.52-2.46Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1177.6,316.67c-3.67-.82-4.08-2.46-5.73,0-1.62,2.46-5.72,23.35,2.06,22.53,7.79-.8,10.24-2.38,7.79-8.37-2.46-5.97-.39-13.35-4.11-14.16Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1223.51,341.22c6.54-.38,7.37-3.39,6.54-8.63-.8-5.27-1.23-8.54-6.96-8.96-5.74-.39-11.06,0-13.93,0s7.82,17.99,14.36,17.6Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1175.98,351.51c-3.69,1.62-2.46,22.12,2.05,23.34,4.51,1.23,11.47,3.7,10.26-3.67-1.23-7.37,0-12.29-3.72-16.4-3.67-4.1-4.9-4.9-8.59-3.26Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1198.81,418.28c-3.99-5.32-6.55-7.36-10.39-13.09-3.86-5.75-9.58-8.21-12.45-8.62-2.87-.41-2.05-4.08-2.87-.41-.82,3.69,1.23,20.48,4.91,24.17s7.39,7.8,12.27,7.39c4.95-.43,12.5-4.1,8.51-9.44Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1281.7,396.89c-.43,2.14,8.18,8.3,11.47,5.01,3.28-3.29,.08-12.7-4.68-12.29-4.74,.41-6.38,5.14-6.79,7.28Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1265.32,684.23c3.28-10.26,6.13-14.75,1.64-18.86-4.51-4.1-6.98-6.14-10.67-4.9-3.69,1.23-7.79,24.98-.41,28.27,7.38,3.28,6.16,5.73,9.44-4.51Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M3026.95,335.07c3.15-11.8,7.07-11,7.07-22.79s-.8-12.32,0-21.07c.77-8.76,1.58-7.2,5.48-15.84,3.92-8.63,4.73-13.34,0-18.83-4.71-5.5-2.13-14.13,3.26-12.57,5.39,1.57,10.89,.77,5.39-8.64-5.52-9.41-1.96-11.77-11.58-3.92-9.63,7.85-9.63,3.14-9.63,7.85s-4.71,32.99-3.15,41.61c1.58,8.62,1.72,26.69-.3,35.33-2.04,8.63,.3,30.63,3.45,18.86Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1147.69,745.43c5.58,5.59,11.16,5.59,17.43,3.48,6.29-2.08,14.66,.6,8.37-6.34-6.27-6.9,4.19-6.21-6.27-6.9-10.46-.68-25.1,4.17-19.52,9.75Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1138.63,827.73c10.46-2.1,16.04-.35,16.04-6.45s-3.17-11-8.21-12.4c-5.04-1.39-18.29,20.93-7.83,18.85Z" />

        </g>
        </svg>
</div>
```

```
    <pre>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Map</title>
    
        <style>
            .cls-4 {
            fill: #7ec353;
            stroke: #020202;
            stroke-width: 4px;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
        
        .cls-4:hover {
            fill: #d1b308; 
        }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="map">
    
            <svg id="Terrain" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4280.57 5494.61">
        
                <g id="0-250m">
                    
                    <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1237.03,239.22c4.1-5.74,1.62-16.81,0-26.24-1.64-9.41-2.05-6.54-8.6-8.6-6.57-2.05-11.08,.41-25.81,0-14.77-.41-32.79-4.52-34.86-4.9-2.03-.43-1.62,4.9-4.51,8.59-2.87,3.69-4.9,4.91-4.9,14.34s2.87,10.24,9.01,14.35c6.14,4.1,15.16,11.06,28.27,12.29,13.11,1.23,20.09,0,30.32,0s6.96-4.08,11.07-9.83Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1142.37,233.9c-4.08-4.11-5.74-4.91-9.83,0-4.08,4.92-11.88,21.71-12.28,26.64-.43,4.9-2.06,15.96,2.24,21.3,4.3,5.32,6.76,12.7,11.69,15.57,4.92,2.87,4.92,9.43,11.05,0,6.16-9.44,7.39-6.57,2.87-13.11-4.51-6.57-13.5-10.67-12.91-16.4,.63-5.73-1.43-16.81,1.86-21.3,3.26-4.49,9.41-8.59,5.31-12.7Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1239.27,361.34c1.45,6.54,1.4,11.49,5.11,15.16,3.73,3.69,16.83,12.27,20.93,7.79,4.11-4.51,10.24-15.57,9.85-20.48-.41-4.92,5.73-9.44,7.77-13.93,2.06-4.52,.84-9.03-5.31-8.61-6.16,.39-11.42,0-16.16,2.45-4.74,2.47-23.62,11.06-22.17,17.63Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1255.47,332.24c3.7-2.87,6.78-.8,6.04-4.3-.7-3.47-1.21-8.4-6.51-8.81-5.26-.39-4.38-1.42-5.26-.39-2.43,2.74,2.05,16.37,5.73,13.5Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1301.37,281.85c4.93-5.34,8.61-9.03,2.87-13.12-5.75-4.08-6.27,.43-7.62,0-1.39-.41-13.27,10.67-8.76,15.58,4.51,4.92,8.61,2.87,13.52-2.46Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1177.6,316.67c-3.67-.82-4.08-2.46-5.73,0-1.62,2.46-5.72,23.35,2.06,22.53,7.79-.8,10.24-2.38,7.79-8.37-2.46-5.97-.39-13.35-4.11-14.16Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1223.51,341.22c6.54-.38,7.37-3.39,6.54-8.63-.8-5.27-1.23-8.54-6.96-8.96-5.74-.39-11.06,0-13.93,0s7.82,17.99,14.36,17.6Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1175.98,351.51c-3.69,1.62-2.46,22.12,2.05,23.34,4.51,1.23,11.47,3.7,10.26-3.67-1.23-7.37,0-12.29-3.72-16.4-3.67-4.1-4.9-4.9-8.59-3.26Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1198.81,418.28c-3.99-5.32-6.55-7.36-10.39-13.09-3.86-5.75-9.58-8.21-12.45-8.62-2.87-.41-2.05-4.08-2.87-.41-.82,3.69,1.23,20.48,4.91,24.17s7.39,7.8,12.27,7.39c4.95-.43,12.5-4.1,8.51-9.44Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1281.7,396.89c-.43,2.14,8.18,8.3,11.47,5.01,3.28-3.29,.08-12.7-4.68-12.29-4.74,.41-6.38,5.14-6.79,7.28Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1265.32,684.23c3.28-10.26,6.13-14.75,1.64-18.86-4.51-4.1-6.98-6.14-10.67-4.9-3.69,1.23-7.79,24.98-.41,28.27,7.38,3.28,6.16,5.73,9.44-4.51Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M3026.95,335.07c3.15-11.8,7.07-11,7.07-22.79s-.8-12.32,0-21.07c.77-8.76,1.58-7.2,5.48-15.84,3.92-8.63,4.73-13.34,0-18.83-4.71-5.5-2.13-14.13,3.26-12.57,5.39,1.57,10.89,.77,5.39-8.64-5.52-9.41-1.96-11.77-11.58-3.92-9.63,7.85-9.63,3.14-9.63,7.85s-4.71,32.99-3.15,41.61c1.58,8.62,1.72,26.69-.3,35.33-2.04,8.63,.3,30.63,3.45,18.86Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1147.69,745.43c5.58,5.59,11.16,5.59,17.43,3.48,6.29-2.08,14.66,.6,8.37-6.34-6.27-6.9,4.19-6.21-6.27-6.9-10.46-.68-25.1,4.17-19.52,9.75Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1138.63,827.73c10.46-2.1,16.04-.35,16.04-6.45s-3.17-11-8.21-12.4c-5.04-1.39-18.29,20.93-7.83,18.85Z" />

        
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    </pre>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The code seems to be working as expected. It is just that you had malformed `HTML`. Missing `g` and `svg` closing tags. Checkout the embedded snippet

Comment: Hello Susbanth,
thanks for your answer and the information about the missing tags. I will fix this.

But my question is, when you hover one island, all other islands should also display as hovered. At the moment, only the island changes its color to yellow, where the mouse is over. But all islands should change their color to yellow, in depended on which island the mouse is over

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements work like normal HTML element, you can add the `<g>` tag which contains all the `<path>` tag a class name, like `color-group`; then rewrite the CSS selector to

```css
.color-group {
  fill: #7ec353;
  stroke: #020202;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.color-group:hover {
  fill: #d1b308;
}
```

there is an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Map</title>
    <style>
        .color-group {
            fill: #7ec353;
            stroke: #020202;
            stroke-width: 4px;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .color-group:hover {
            fill: #d1b308;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="map">
        <svg id="Terrain" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4280.57 5494.61">
            <g class="color-group" id="0-250m">
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1237.03,239.22c4.1-5.74,1.62-16.81,0-26.24-1.64-9.41-2.05-6.54-8.6-8.6-6.57-2.05-11.08,.41-25.81,0-14.77-.41-32.79-4.52-34.86-4.9-2.03-.43-1.62,4.9-4.51,8.59-2.87,3.69-4.9,4.91-4.9,14.34s2.87,10.24,9.01,14.35c6.14,4.1,15.16,11.06,28.27,12.29,13.11,1.23,20.09,0,30.32,0s6.96-4.08,11.07-9.83Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1142.37,233.9c-4.08-4.11-5.74-4.91-9.83,0-4.08,4.92-11.88,21.71-12.28,26.64-.43,4.9-2.06,15.96,2.24,21.3,4.3,5.32,6.76,12.7,11.69,15.57,4.92,2.87,4.92,9.43,11.05,0,6.16-9.44,7.39-6.57,2.87-13.11-4.51-6.57-13.5-10.67-12.91-16.4,.63-5.73-1.43-16.81,1.86-21.3,3.26-4.49,9.41-8.59,5.31-12.7Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"                     d="M1239.27,361.34c1.45,6.54,1.4,11.49,5.11,15.16,3.73,3.69,16.83,12.27,20.93,7.79,4.11-4.51,10.24-15.57,9.85-20.48-.41-4.92,5.73-9.44,7.77-13.93,2.06-4.52,.84-9.03-5.31-8.61-6.16,.39-11.42,0-16.16,2.45-4.74,2.47-23.62,11.06-22.17,17.63Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1255.47,332.24c3.7-2.87,6.78-.8,6.04-4.3-.7-3.47-1.21-8.4-6.51-8.81-5.26-.39-4.38-1.42-5.26-.39-2.43,2.74,2.05,16.37,5.73,13.5Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1301.37,281.85c4.93-5.34,8.61-9.03,2.87-13.12-5.75-4.08-6.27,.43-7.62,0-1.39-.41-13.27,10.67-8.76,15.58,4.51,4.92,8.61,2.87,13.52-2.46Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1177.6,316.67c-3.67-.82-4.08-2.46-5.73,0-1.62,2.46-5.72,23.35,2.06,22.53,7.79-.8,10.24-2.38,7.79-8.37-2.46-5.97-.39-13.35-4.11-14.16Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1223.51,341.22c6.54-.38,7.37-3.39,6.54-8.63-.8-5.27-1.23-8.54-6.96-8.96-5.74-.39-11.06,0-13.93,0s7.82,17.99,14.36,17.6Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1175.98,351.51c-3.69,1.62-2.46,22.12,2.05,23.34,4.51,1.23,11.47,3.7,10.26-3.67-1.23-7.37,0-12.29-3.72-16.4-3.67-4.1-4.9-4.9-8.59-3.26Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1198.81,418.28c-3.99-5.32-6.55-7.36-10.39-13.09-3.86-5.75-9.58-8.21-12.45-8.62-2.87-.41-2.05-4.08-2.87-.41-.82,3.69,1.23,20.48,4.91,24.17s7.39,7.8,12.27,7.39c4.95-.43,12.5-4.1,8.51-9.44Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1281.7,396.89c-.43,2.14,8.18,8.3,11.47,5.01,3.28-3.29,.08-12.7-4.68-12.29-4.74,.41-6.38,5.14-6.79,7.28Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1265.32,684.23c3.28-10.26,6.13-14.75,1.64-18.86-4.51-4.1-6.98-6.14-10.67-4.9-3.69,1.23-7.79,24.98-.41,28.27,7.38,3.28,6.16,5.73,9.44-4.51Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M3026.95,335.07c3.15-11.8,7.07-11,7.07-22.79s-.8-12.32,0-21.07c.77-8.76,1.58-7.2,5.48-15.84,3.92-8.63,4.73-13.34,0-18.83-4.71-5.5-2.13-14.13,3.26-12.57,5.39,1.57,10.89,.77,5.39-8.64-5.52-9.41-1.96-11.77-11.58-3.92-9.63,7.85-9.63,3.14-9.63,7.85s-4.71,32.99-3.15,41.61c1.58,8.62,1.72,26.69-.3,35.33-2.04,8.63,.3,30.63,3.45,18.86Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1147.69,745.43c5.58,5.59,11.16,5.59,17.43,3.48,6.29-2.08,14.66,.6,8.37-6.34-6.27-6.9,4.19-6.21-6.27-6.9-10.46-.68-25.1,4.17-19.52,9.75Z" />
                <path class="cls-4"
                    d="M1138.63,827.73c10.46-2.1,16.04-.35,16.04-6.45s-3.17-11-8.21-12.4c-5.04-1.39-18.29,20.93-7.83,18.85Z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```